# Redirect to new URL but keep the old URL

Tags: redirect, nginx

I created a website called mydomain.com.

Per requirement, I need to switch to the new domain, new content, but not immediately, I want customer see the content of the page as like: **abc.com** but the URL remains the old URL itself **mydomain.com**:

Can someone help me to point out the way to proceed my work ?

I have tried but not work, URL changed.

```
location /content/unittests/jw/presspage/ {
    proxy_pass http://client.presspage.com/?subfolder=1&clienthash=d1b8db7c94cfc27c372dca0312fb419a&trail=$uri&$args;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

I edited the code as above. but it still redirected to the original page abc.com/content/unittests/jw/presspage/index.html

Comment: Don't use `proxy_redirect`. Try using `proxy_pass http://example.com/;`. Also, don't forget the trailing slash before the semi-colon.

Comment: @DonovanHernandez Thanks. I tried but it does not work for me. the page still remains the same content. Could I use rewrite in this situation ?

Comment: Can you show the full location block? And you're sure that `/somepath` isn't redirecting you to `/somepath/` first? Did you restart nginx?

Comment: @DonovanHernandez I edited the code as above.